# Yii2 Validation: Image may not be empty

Tags: yii2

I use ActiveRecord and I want to upload an image. But Yii always says that the fileInput is empty.

My model has an extra attribute called "image" and the rules are

```
[['image'], 'required', 'on' => 'new'],
[['image'], 'image', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],
```

And I use this Code in the controller

```
$model = new Picture();
$model->scenario = 'new';

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
    $model->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
    $model->image->saveAs($model->savePath($this->plugin).'/'.$model->id.'.jpg');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try            [['image'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'png, jpg'],

Comment: does also not work, the problem is the required, the file will be saved if the required is removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code is working for me, hope it will help you,

```
[['logo'], 'required', 'on' => 'create'],
[['logo'], 'file', 'skipOnError' => true,'extensions' => 'png, jpg, gif'],

$model = new Company();
$model->scenario = 'create';

 if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $logo = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'logo');
            if (!is_null($logo)) {
                $model->logo = $logo->name;
                if($model->validate()) {
                    $dirpath = dirname(getcwd());
                    $logo->saveAs($dirpath . '/admin/uploads/' . $logo->baseName . '.' . $logo->extension);
                    $model->save();
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->Id]);
                }
            }
        }
```